# Failed to import ovf appliances in virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I use VMplayer and I made a virtual machine inside of it, which I'm trying to import into virtualbox, via:

```
ovftool "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Virtual Machines\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.vmx" C:\Users\admin\export.ovf
```

It will done correctly. But while importing this in virtualbox error will occur.
Error is

```
Failed to import appliance C:\Users\admin\export.ovf

Error reading C:\Users\admin\export.ovf: unknown element "config" under Item element, line 47.
```

what to do..

Answer (score 2):

google helps with this sort of thing

see point 3 of this http://praitheesh.blogspot.com.au/2013_09_01_archive.html

but I would take a backup first

I think the idea is to edit the OVF file as it is XML